# Setting DateFormat to current date and time

Tags: java, android, date, time

I am using java.text.DateFormat in order to display the date and time for a user of my application. Below is my code to test the output.

The issue is that the date is being displayed as 1970 (see output below). How can I update this to the current date and time.

**Current Output:**

```
 1 Jan 1970 01:00:00
```

**Current code:**

```
DateFormat[] formats = new DateFormat[] {

        DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(),

        };

        for (DateFormat df : formats) {

            Log.d("Dateformat", "Date format: " + (df.format(new Date(0))));
        }
```

Alternatively if the above is not possible, I am able to get the current time and date using the **following method:**

```
Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String date= now.toString();
```

**Output:**

```
20140722T133458Europe/London(2,202,3600,1,1406032498)
```

How can I adjust this in order to make it readable for a user?

Comment: Solved the issue thank you!

Comment: Is this a string value?

Comment: Because I would like to save the date as a string but I am getting errors as I cannot create an instance of DateFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write `new Date()` instead of `new Date(0)` in your first snippet. When you write `new Date(some number)` it makes a date which is that many milliseconds after `1/1/1970 00:00:00Z`

Comment: Thank you, how can I save this date as a String. I cannot do so currently as I cannot create an instance of DateFomat outside of my for loop?

Comment: What is stopping you from creating `DateFormat` objects wherever you like?

Comment: I was able to solve it by: SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat();
  
  String myDate= df.format(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                 .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) 
       )
```

## `Instant`

The accepted [Answer by Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887811/642706) is correct.

But know that you are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
```

To generate a String representing that moment formatting according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, simply call `toString`.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To view the same moment through the lens of some region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );  // Adjust from UTC to a specific time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

For presentation to the user, let java.time automatically localize using the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) class.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).